# python create a column with polygons from column with coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, shapely

I need to add a column to my df (df['poly']) which takes the coordinates (lat and long) in df['coords'] and converts them into polygons of different sizes. Some key_id have only two points while others have almost 20 points

I tried with shapely but I don't know how to proceed. What can I do?

My df has a similar structure:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame ({'key_id': ['151,'244','245'],

                    'coords': [[[-8.37793, 37.42726],
                               [-8.29726, 37.42958],
                               [-8.1975, 37.35019],
                               [-8.07657, 37.3241],
                               [-7.98004, 37.40123],
                               [-7.73969, 37.49087],
                               [-7.51269, 37.52626]],

                              [[28.44261, 38.10466],
                               [28.61609, 38.08959]],

                              [[-5.7376, 40.29416],
                               [-5.78421, 40.292],
                               [-5.81097, 40.34586],
                               [-5.92499, 40.28829],
                               [-5.97971, 40.29835],
                               [-6.22156, 40.48251],
                               [-6.53513, 40.34072], 
                               [-6.59286, 40.27262],
                               [-6.77174, 40.24218],
                               [-6.86514, 40.27069]]]

                   })
```

Comment: I do not understand. You have coords, which is an array of array of coordinates. Are the "array of coordinates" the polygons? What do you want as result? Why do you use pandas? Note: You tagged "gis", not "pandas". Also the structure of the data seems very strange. You need to explain more. Maybe you want to check geopandas (never used, but if you mix structures, maybe it is appropriate).

Comment: I created this df from Eurostat NUTS map geojson. I need a column with Polygon properties to check if a point is inside a polygon. As far as I know, it is possible to create it using the shapely library that convert arrays but I don't know how to do this. I've heard about geopandas but I have problems to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- downloaded: https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2021-60m.geojson.zip
- simple use of **geopandas**, no need to work out how to build polygons

```
import json
import geopandas as gpd
from pathlib import Path
# NUTS_BN_60M_2021_3035.geojson
p = Path.home().joinpath("Downloads/ref-nuts-2021-60m").joinpath("NUTS_BN_60M_2021_3035.geojson")
with open(p) as f: js = json.load(f)
gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(js)
```

#### sample output

|  | geometry | EU_FLAG | EFTA_FLAG | CC_FLAG | LEVL_CODE | NUTS_BN_ID | COAS_FLAG | OTHR_FLAG | FID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | LINESTRING (4710072.1544 1558882.7113, 4682530.865 1568851.5189) | T | F | F | 0 | 155 | T | F | 155 |
| 1 | LINESTRING (4750146.4639 1575613.1831, 4719326.4198 1565032.5462) | T | F | F | 3 | 156 | F | F | 156 |
| 2 | LINESTRING (4750146.4639 1575613.1831, 4771337.8016 1529624.4864) | T | F | F | 3 | 157 | F | F | 157 |
| 3 | LINESTRING (5708788.4877 1703805.8981, 5716323.6218 1677819.7608, 5699205.566099999 1671425.5691, 5689132.9338 1687843.7667, 5674013.6588 1672224.311, 5660024.3965 1679252.6566, 5666955.0392 1699891.5505, 5708788.4877 1703805.8981) | T | F | F | 0 | 158 | T | F | 158 |
| 4 | LINESTRING (2862160.935 1681571.7459, 2817387.2651 1732249.228499999, 2777974.267 1743031.7994) | T | F | F | 0 | 159 | T | F | 159 |